# Object Localization

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[image: Tray with valves]

I have a image of valve placed on the tray. I need to find position of each valve in image and if there is no valve also shall be identified. Because of illunination I always have image similar to this with corner valves are cant be seen fully.

Kinldy tell me what method is optimal to find position of valves.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Binarization and connected components labeling will do the trick. But you may have to correct the parallax.

Comment: If you always have same kind of image, then using template matching or some descriptors like HOG over one valve, will also give good results.

Comment: Blur, threshold, findcontours, and this is my results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKL8o.png

Comment: I tried shape detection (circular) but as corner valves are not cercular because of illumination . i didnt succeed- tried contour extraction.

Comment: @Silencer.  Method you toldlooks very good in images you shared.  Thank you. I will try that.